# conditional output of a text box in MS Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have got a form up and running and one of the fields in the form called 'plan' output a value based on values in other fields on the form. The form has single mastertable as the record source. There are combo boxes and filters on them in vba. Everything works fine , but if I need to add a new record, I am directed to a new form and there when the user enters values for 7 required fields, the 2 plan fields (for 2 different activities) should populate automatically based on the entries by the user. So, there are certain conditions and criterias on the values entered by users, which together have a unique "plan" value There are several conditions and criteria for values in other fields and based on that the value in the plan field is returned. Any clues on how I can do that? Should I define variables in vba which holds the values entered by user and then use if or switch case statement which contains sql string ?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried, there isn't enough information to go on yet.

Comment: Possibly use VBA if the form is set for Single view. Maybe need to build  a lookup table of the values and criteria. Then either include the table in the form RecordSource or use DLookup() expression in textbox.

Comment: The form is setup for single view. Its a second form where the users are redirected if they want to add, delete or edit a record. So, when they chose to add a new record, they should enter values for some required fields and based on those values and our criteria , the 2 plan fields should populate automatically. I have these criterias on values and resultant plans in a excel file in couple of tables or blocks.

Comment: I have a mastertable as the record source for the form. How i understand, i can't have multiple look up table for one form field. The criteria includes picking up values from multiple fields on the form entered by the user.

Comment: Private Sub Plangruppe_Falten_GotFocus()
Select Case FaltenStr
   Case 50051602
      If Me.Material = "h" Or "as" Or "vs" Or "pwr" & Me.Edel_stahl = Null & Me.FH > 4.5 & Me.FH < 10 & Me.DF < 60 Then
         Me.Plangruppe_Falten = 50051602
      End If
End Select
End Sub